# Binding em Datagrid - Não é possível acessar um objeto descartado

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tenho um `datagrid` com avaliações cuja primeira coluna é o NOME DO PACIENTE. Porém na hora de colocar o Binding `Paciente.Nome`ele dá erro. Dentro de avaliação existe um objeto de paciente.

**CÓDIGO DO DATAGRID**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridPSc" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="850" MouseDoubleClick="DataGridPSC_OnMouseDoubleClick">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Paciente" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path= Paciente.Nome}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data da Avaliação" Width="125" Binding="{Binding Path=DataAvaliacao, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
```

**CÓDIGO DE PREENCHIMENTO DA DATAGRID**

```
DataGridPSc.Items.Clear(); ;
var avaliacoes = ManagerAvaliacaoPSc.Avaliacoes().OrderByDescending(a => a.DataAvaliacao);
foreach (var a in avaliacoes)
{
   DataGridPSc.Items.Add(a);
}
```

**MANAGER AVALIAÇÃO PSC**

```
public static List<Avaliacao_Psc> Avaliacoes()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new TrabalhoDataContext())
            {
                return db.Avaliacao_Pscs.OrderByDescending(a => a.DataAvaliacao).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao tentar carregar as avaliações: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

**IMAGEM COM O ERRO**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o código onde o erro ocorre.

Comment: @ramaral ocorre no momento em que o form com o datagrid é carregado, ou seja, no onload, que contém o código de preenchimento da datagrid que está nesse post

Comment: Resolvi partir para um plano b. Criei uma view fazendo o Inner Join entre paciente e avaliação. Resolveu o problema até o momento.